# gcsfuse on Alpine Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse, alpine

I try to use gcsfuse in order to store application source code on a GCP bucket, here's my Dockerfile:

```
ARG VERSION

FROM golang:1.12.5-alpine3.9 as gcsfuse-builder

ENV GOPATH /go

RUN apk --update add git=2.20.1-r0 fuse=2.9.8-r2 fuse-dev=2.9.8-r2 \
    && go get -u github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse

FROM php:$VERSION as base

ARG REVISION

ENV APP_DIR=/srv/app \
    APP_ENV=prod \
    APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER=index.php \
    APP_LOCALE=fr \
    APP_USER=test-user \
    APP_USER_GROUP=test \
    APP_PORT=8080 \
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
    NGINX_DIR=/etc/nginx \
    NGINX_VERSION=1.14.2-r1 \
    PHP_FPM_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/ \
    SUPERVISORD_CONF_DIR=/etc/supervisor \
    SUPERVISOR_VERSION=3.3.4-r1 \
    BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR=/build-scripts \
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/srv/app/bucket.json

# Supervisord conf to be copied at the end.
COPY docker/prod/php/scripts/*.sh $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/

# Core dependencies installation (installed as a virtual package in order to remove it later)
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fuse-deps curl sshfs fuse \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .bash bash=4.4.19-r1 \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .core-php-deps icu-dev=62.1-r0 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
        opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && apk del .build-deps .phpize-deps-configure

# User creation
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted --virtual .user-deps gosu=1.10-r0 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && addgroup $APP_USER_GROUP \
    && adduser -D -h /home/portfolio -s /bin/bash -G $APP_USER_GROUP $APP_USER \
    && chown -R $APP_USER $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR \
    && apk del .user-deps

# Nginx & Supervisor installation
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .http-deps nginx=$NGINX_VERSION supervisor=$SUPERVISOR_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Filesystem (gcsfuse)
COPY --from=gcsfuse-builder /go/bin/gcsfuse /usr/local/bin
COPY bucket.json $APP_DIR/bucket.json

# Filesystem (gcsfuse binding)
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .filesystem-deps curl fuse fuse-dev rsync \
    && mkdir -p $APP_DIR $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR \
    && chown -R $APP_USER $APP_DIR \
    && chmod -R 755 $APP_DIR \
    && gcsfuse mybucketname $APP_DIR

COPY docker/prod/php/conf/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/prod/php/conf/fpm.conf $PHP_FPM_CONF_DIR/fpm.conf
COPY docker/prod/nginx/conf/nginx.conf $NGINX_DIR/nginx.conf
COPY docker/prod/supervisord/supervisord.conf $SUPERVISORD_CONF_DIR/supervisord.conf

# Used to check that PHP-FPM works
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ping || exit 1

# Production build
FROM base as production

COPY docker/prod/nginx/conf/test.conf $NGINX_DIR/conf.d/test.conf

WORKDIR $APP_DIR

COPY . .

# The vendors are installed after the whole project is copied, this way, we can dump the autoload properly.
# The unrequired directories are also removed.
RUN /bin/bash "$BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install_composer.sh" \
    && /bin/bash "$BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/composer_dependencies.sh" \
    && rm -rf $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR \
        /usr/bin/git* \
        /lib/apk/db/installed \
        /usr/local/bin/composer \
        node_modules/

EXPOSE $APP_PORT 443

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

The image can be built without gcsfuse but when the build use:

`gcsfuse mybucketname $APP_DIR`

Here's the error that I encounter:

`fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`

Is there any workaround to get it working during `docker build`?

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

Install gcsfuse only in build phase. Put the `gcsfuse` mount part in script and use the script in `CMD`.

Then run your container with `--privileged`

Comment: I can't run it with `--privileged` as my container is executed in Cloud Run :)

Answer (score 1):

You must expose `/dev/fuse` from the command line or from `docker-compose.yml` and set `privileged`:

```
myproject:
  privileged: true
  devices:
    - "/dev/fuse:/dev/fuse"
```

My Dockerfile adapted from Ernest's docker-gcsfuse:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
ARG GCSFUSE_VERSION=0.27.0
RUN apk --update --no-cache add git fuse fuse-dev;
RUN go get -d github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse
RUN go install github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/tools/build_gcsfuse
RUN build_gcsfuse ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse /tmp ${GCSFUSE_VERSION}

COPY --from=builder /tmp/bin/gcsfuse /usr/bin
COPY --from=builder /tmp/sbin/mount.gcsfuse /usr/sbin
RUN ln -s /usr/sbin/mount.gcsfuse /usr/sbin/mount.fuse.gcsfuse
WORKDIR /
```

Mount through fstab (`key_file` is optional):

```
echo "$BUCKET $MOUNTPOINT gcsfuse rw,user,noauto,key_file=$KEYFILE_PATH" >> /etc/fstab
mount.gcsfuse $BUCKET $MOUNTPOINT
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've checked this and it seems that I cannot run `gcsfuse my-bucket filespath` during the `docker build` phase :/

Comment: I updated the answer as implemented at my own project and works. You can obtain your key file (in json format) at the Service Account settings.

Comment: I've followed your code and tried to use the `gcsfuse` command during `docker build`, it seems that using the `mount.gcsfuse` isn't possible as the executable isn't found :/

Comment: @Guikingone If I'm not mistaken, it's been renamed to mount_gcsfuse

Answer (score 1):

When using last versions of go, you need to use GO111MODULE=off to avoid errors.

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
ARG GCSFUSE_VERSION=0.27.0
ENV GO111MODULE=off
RUN apk --update --no-cache add git fuse fuse-dev;
RUN go get -d github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse
RUN go install github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/tools/build_gcsfuse
RUN build_gcsfuse ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse /tmp ${GCSFUSE_VERSION}

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /tmp/bin/gcsfuse /usr/bin
COPY --from=builder /tmp/sbin/mount.gcsfuse /usr/sbin
RUN ln -s /usr/sbin/mount.gcsfuse /usr/sbin/mount.fuse.gcsfuse
```